# How to get the cell state of datagridview in C#

Tags: c#

I have a datagridview, dgv1 with 10 columns in C# form, it is bounded with a DB table. The second column is a combobox with the values, close/open/for consideration.... User is able to modify the vaulues in any cells. After the modification is done, user can press Save button to save the changes to DB table. 
But there is another task needs to be done before saving the change: if any second column's value changed, a DB stored procedure must be called.

My issue is that I do not know how to find out if the cell's value changed or not, and also I need to know the previous values, previous & current values have to pass to stored procedure.

```
foreach (DataRow rows in dtList.Rows)
{
   if(rows.RowState.ToString() == "Modified")
   {
      if(rows.cell(1) is changed)
      { 
         call stored procedure here... 
      }
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: WinForms, WPF, etc.? You can just store the `DataGridView`'s data in a `DataTable` when the form (assuming WinForms) initialises/loads. Then check for changes (against the binded `DataTable`) when the 'Save' button is pressed.

Comment: KillerCam has a great suggestion, another way would be to store the values in HashTable sort of like doin an Inline Delta if you are familiar with the term Delta in regards to a DB.. if this were Oracle then it would be totally easy because of the :Old and :New that you could get at.. Now that I think about it.. why not capture the Current Value on the On RoW Click event .. and what ever row they are on capture the current state.. and it it changes capture it as well and then Compare store them in a Property..

Answer (score 0):

One simple (but probably not the best way!) would be to use a `List` to store the `ComboBox` values in. At form load we can write:

```
const int yourCell = 1;
List<string> colComboValues = new List<string>();
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in this.dataGridView.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell CB = dgvRow.Cells[yourCell] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
    colComboValues.Add(CB.Value.ToString());
}
```

and then on save we can check which of those `ComboBox`'s have changed using:

```
// On Save.
int nIdx = 0;
foreach (DataGridViewRow dgvRow in this.dataGridView.Rows)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell CB = dgvRow.Cells[yourCell] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
    if (String.Compare(CB.Value.ToString(), colComboValues[nIdx++], false) != 0)
    {
        // Value has changed!
    }
    else
    {
        // Value has not.
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions!!! I am going to try Killercam's suggestion first. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If you subscribe to the CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit events and add the results to a dictionary if there was a change, the end result would be that you simply iterate over the dictionary which would contain the cell as its key and (in my case object in your case combobox values) the previous value, before editing.

```
    Dictionary<DataGridViewCell, object> cvDict = new Dictionary<DataGridViewCell, object>();

    private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell dgcv = (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (!cvDict.ContainsKey(dgcv))
        {
            cvDict.Add(dgcv, dgcv.Value);
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCell dgcv = (sender as DataGridView).Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
        if (cvDict.ContainsKey(dgcv))
        {
            if (cvDict[dgcv].Equals(dgcv.Value))
            {
                cvDict.Remove(dgcv);
            }
        }
    }
```